# how to calculate distance of data points from cluster centers using python

Tags: python, data-analysis, data-science

I've used scipy.spatial.distance.cdist library, but I'm not able to generate results in a loop.

Is there any way using for loop?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the code you have already tried to generate the results with? Also, be more specific as to what output you would like.

Comment: You have to be _much_ more specific. Include your code and sample data and ask _specific_ questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

x1 =np.array([(1,3),(2,4),(5,6)])
x2 =[(3,7),(4,8),(6,9)]
cdist(x1,x2,metric='euclidean')

Out[20]:
array([[ 4.47213595,  5.83095189,  7.81024968],
       [ 3.16227766,  4.47213595,  6.40312424],
       [ 2.23606798,  2.23606798,  3.16227766]])

np.power((1-3)**2 +(3-7)**2,1/2)
Out[23]: 4.4721359549995796
```

reference:http://blog.csdn.net/kancy110/article/details/75675574